# Cant connect to postgres database inside docker container

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, asynchronous, docker-compose

My problem is I have a script that should scrap data and put it inside postgres database, however it has a problem to reach out postgres container.

When I run my docker-compose here is the result:

```
           Name                     Command               State              Ports             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
orcsearch_dev-db_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp       
orcsearch_flask_1    gunicorn wsgi:application  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 8000/tcp
```

We can clearly see that postgres is on 5432 port.

This is my python script database setting:(ofcourse I removed password for obvious reason)

```
class App():
    settings = {
        'db_host': 'db',
        'db_user': 'postgres',
        'db_pass': '',
        'db_db': 'orc',
    }
    db = None
    proxies = None
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - pip-cache:/root/.cache
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - "dev-db:db"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres@db:5432/postgres
    stdin_open: true
    command: gunicorn wsgi:application -w 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --log-level debug --reload
    networks:
      app:
        aliases:
          - flask

  dev-db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      app:
        aliases:
          - dev-db

volumes:
  pip-cache:
    driver: local

networks:
  app:
```

When going into exec flask bash(inside flask container) and running script command I get this error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Obviously there is postgres running on this port and I cant figure out what wrong do I do. Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are using DSN instead of URI, and PostgreSQL thinks that "db" is not a host because it's hard to tell if "db" is host or path to socket. To fix it, use URI instead of DSN if you use >=9.2 version of PostgreSQL.

Example of URI:
`postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING

Answer (score 0):

In your App class it should be `'db_host': 'dev-db',` Seems like that hostname is exposed, not `db`.

Comment: You should also try to put `dev-db` in your `environtment: DATABASE_URL...`.

Comment: Why not make it simpler and and set all references to db same, say `db`. That way you could define only one value, like `links: "db"`, and call the service `db:`, etc... Try to debug it like that.

Comment: I did try, somehow it still says it cant connect to postgres...
It is also worth mentioning that gunicron has no problem with connecting to postgres, async script do.

Comment: Why you have port 8000 when  docker-compose ps? Are you sure your `DATABASE_URL` var in flask has the right values for postgres host and database?

Comment: Kamil answer is correct and it helped me, thank you for your trying though!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is related to the fact that you're using the network and the link together. Try remove the link and change the postgres address to `dev-db` or change the alias to:

```
networks:
  app:
    aliases:
      - dev-db
      - db
```